# Reactor sequential() seems to lose events

Tags: java, project-reactor

In a Flux, where the stream is parallelized then later sequenced, it seems that the supposed round-robin nature of the sequential() method is not being consistently enforced, and it appears that events may end up so far out of sequence that they are effectively lost. This behavior is not consistent over multiple runs, with some runs being spot-on in sequence, and others varying wildly.

I understand that events will likely arrive out of order to some degree, but that degree, even in a simple example, can be enough that some events are delayed beyond their useful lifespan.

For a fixed set of data this may be perfectly acceptable, but for an event stream from Kafka it can result in data loss that is hard to debug.

In this example, over multiple runs, you may see every even number from 2-1000 printed in order, then on another run see a series of even numbers starting at around 2 and going as high as the seventeen hundreds, with some two-digit numbers never appearing in the sequence.

I have varied the number of parallel threads, the sequential prefetch, added publishOn and subscribeOn steps, but nothing seems to make this any more or less predictable.

```
    Flux.range(1, 5000)
        .parallel(64)
        .runOn(Schedulers.newParallel("test", 64))
        .filter(integer -> integer % 2 == 0)
        .sequential()
        .take(500)
        .doOnNext(System.out::println)
        .blockLast();
  }
```

Certainly, over a long-enough timespan, every value would appear, but in practical terms some events may be delayed too long for them to be useful.

Round-robin is not perfect, but this doesn't seem like round-robin to me. Is there something I am doing wrong here, or is this a deeper issue?

Comment: With multiple threads and rails the result will never be predictable. `sequential` has nothing to do with that. In your comment you wrote _"you will get most of your events from one rail"_, which is disproved by yourself with _"you may see every even number from 2-1000 printed in order"_

Comment: Do you have a recommendation to get more even flow of ParallelFlux events?

Answer (score 0):

I've tried running your example and every time I get exactly 500 items.

You cannot expect it to produce a predictable sequence because the processing is parallel, and you most probably have less cores than the thread count you're using here (64). Some threads will not receive enough CPU to do their tasks, and other threads will win because of it, and `take(500)` selects the winning numbers.

The distribution of `parallel` is round robin, but the processing is up to the thread scheduler.

Comment: True that you get 500 items. The problem is that you do not get the items anywhere close to equally from from each rail. Even if you drop it down to 2 parallel rails you will get most of your events from one rail, then the other. 

The problem is that some events get so delayed that they may never come through in a reasonable time, at least not with the Flux I have here. I am hoping that there is a way to get a more even distribution from the rails.